# Find the derivative of the inverse function, $Dg(0,1)$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by the equation
\begin{equation} f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)\end{equation}

Parts (a) and (b) of the problem asked me to show that $f$ is one-to-one on the set $A$ consisting of all $(x,y)$ with $x>0$, and to find set $B=f(A)$, which was easy enough to do. Part (c) asks

> If $g$ is the inverse function, find $Dg(0,1)$.

What I thought to do was to find the matrix $Df$ and find the inverse of it, but I am finding that very challenging to do (here I thought I had my linear algebra skills in check!) Because what I get is that

$Df=
\begin{bmatrix}
2x &2y\\
-2y & 2x
\end{bmatrix}$

And when I try to find the inverse, i get to the step

$
\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & 1/2 & 0\\
0 & \frac{x^2+y^2}{x} & \frac{y}{2x} & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}$

And i feel like maybe this is not the correct method to finding the inverse...?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the formula for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: Hint : in complex coordinate $f(z) = z^2$

Comment: @N.H. Thanks for the hint. I got the correct answer using your method, but it's weird that when I use the other method being suggested that I do not get the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix the differential ($f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))\;;u=x^2-y^2\;;v=2xy$):

$$Df=
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial u/\partial x &\partial u/\partial y\\
\partial v/\partial x & \partial v/\partial y
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2x &-2y\\
2y & 2x
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, with the invaluable aid of the commentators, the inverse is

$$Dg(f(x,y))=\dfrac{1}{\vert Df\vert}\begin{pmatrix}2x &2y\\ -2y & 2x\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{4(x^2+y^2)}\begin{pmatrix}2x &2y\\ -2y & 2x\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{2(x^2+y^2)}\begin{pmatrix}x &y\\ -y & x\end{pmatrix}$$

We have to find the values for wich $f(x,y)=(0,1)$, so is, $x^2-y^2=0$ and $2xy=1\implies (x,y)=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ or $(x,y)=(-1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2})$. But $x\gt0$, so we drop the solution with the negatives. Then,

$$Dg(0,1)=Dg(f(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}))=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2}/2 &\sqrt{2}/2\\-\sqrt{2}/2 &\sqrt{2}/2\end{pmatrix}=$$

$$Dg(0,1)=\dfrac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2} &\sqrt{2}\\-\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of a $2$x$2$ matrix is as follows
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc} \begin{bmatrix}d &-b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ok I guess the reason I didnt think it was that is because my professor gave me the answer to be $ 1/4 \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 2 & \sqrt 2 \\ -\sqrt 2 & \sqrt 2 \end{bmatrix}$ which doesnt match...

Comment: You're forgetting to divide by the determinant! That's just the adjugate.

Comment: Yea, I still don't get the correct answer guys. I appreciate your help, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When I do it this way, I get the inverse of $Df$ to be $\frac{1}{2x^2+2y^2} \begin{bmatrix}  2x& 2y\\ -2y & 2x\end{bmatrix}$, and when evaluated at $(0,1)$, it is incorrect.

Comment: @jgcello I guess you shall evaluate that at $(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$? The inverse function thm says if $g$ is the inverse, then $Dg(f(a))=[Df(a)]^{-1}$.